# Custom/Manual PHP function to retrieve category hierarchy from wordpress tables?

Tags: php, wordpress

i am looking for a function to fetch wordpress category hierarchy from wordpress tables (wp_terms, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy) **WITHOUT using wordPress functions / templates**.

i am basically looking to fetch categories (parent/child) relationship and then I want to insert them into my own CMS table. For this i must know "**What Category Comes under What? (with all the sub-sub (multiple) directories)**"

So far I made this:

```
$sql="SELECT a.term_id,a.description,a.parent,a.count,b.name,b.slug
FROM wp_term_taxonomy a INNER JOIN wp_terms b WHERE a.term_id=b.term_id
AND a.taxonomy='category';
";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo($row['name'].'<br>');
}
exit;
```

This function displays all the categories but NOT the hierarchy and i am **NOT able to get the Child Parent** thing..

Can anyone help me with this please?

Regards

Comment: Can I ask why you are avoiding WordPress functions? Your code risks being made redundant in future revisions.

Comment: hi @George Reith ..Actually there was an old blog of mine made with wordpress. Since wordpress became hell slow and i developed my own CMS system and now I want to migrate all my categories hierarchically from wordpress to my own CMS .. everything is done.. I am only stuck with just getting category hierarchy from wordpress by using manual php function..

Comment: Ah ok, so it's a one time use thing. I don't have answer I'm afraid just curious.

Comment: No.. it is not just one time use thing @George Reith :) I will use it further for the clients with whom I will Install my own CMS. those whose servers are being killed by the WordPress and they want to retain all the post and categories and migrate to very very lighter CMS system :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that hard. First I'd wrap that recursive stuff by letting it behave like a [`RecursiveIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php):

```
class RecursiveCategoryIterator implements RecursiveIterator {
    const ID_FIELD = 'term_id';
    const PARENT_FIELD = 'parent';

    private $_data;
    private $_root;
    private $_position = 0;

    public function __construct(array $data, $root_id = 0) {
        $this->_data = $data;
        $this->_root = $root_id;
    }

    public function valid() {
        return isset($this->_data[$this->_root][$this->_position]);
    }

    public function hasChildren() {
        $subid = $this->_data[$this->_root][$this->_position][self::ID_FIELD];
        return isset($this->_data[$subid])
            && is_array($this->_data[$subid]);
    }

    public function next() {
        $this->_position++;
    }

    public function current() {
        return $this->_data[$this->_root][$this->_position];
    }

    public function getChildren() {
        return new self($this->_data,
            $this->_data[$this->_root][$this->_position][self::ID_FIELD]);
    }

    public function rewind() {
        $this->_position = 0;
    }

    public function key() {
        return $this->_position;
    }

    public static function createFromResult($result) {
        $menu_array = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $menu_array[$row[self::PARENT_FIELD]][] = $row;
        }

        return new self($menu_array);
    }
}
```

Now why would I do that? First, because you can re-use id for displaying the tree, or do other stuff with it like import it in your own table. Second, if you have to test your code, you can just put in some other `RecursiveIterator` as a mock (for example a `RecursiveArrayIterator`).

Now the second part, the actual import of the word-press data:

```
// your original query
$sql="SELECT a.term_id,a.description,a.parent,a.count,b.name,b.slug
FROM wp_term_taxonomy a INNER JOIN wp_terms b WHERE a.term_id=b.term_id
AND a.taxonomy='category';
";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbh);

// always test for failure
if($result === false) {
    die("query failed: ". mysql_error());
}

// create the iterator from the result set
$wpterms = RecursiveCategoryIterator::createFromResult($result);

// and import it. 
insert_it($wpterms, 0);

// the function which does all the dirty work.
function insert_it($iterator, $parent_id = 0) {
    foreach($iterator as $row) {
        // insert the row, just edit the query, and don't forget
        // to escape the values. if you have an insert function,
        // use it by all means
        $qry = 'INSERT INTO my_table (myparent, myname, ...)'
            . ' VALUES (\'' . mysql_real_escape_string($parent_id)
            . '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($row['name']) . '\', ....)';

        $status = mysql_query($qry);

        if($status === false) {
            // insert failed - rollback and abort
            die("hard: " . mysql_error());
        }

        // you need to pass the id of the new row
        // so the "child rows" have their respective parent
        $cid = mysql_insert_id();

        // insert the children too
        if($iterator->hasChildren()) {
            insert_it($iterator->getChildren(), $cid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think i need to test it.. it seems a bit working.. will accept your question once I am fully tested.. Thank you :)

Comment: Hey @vstm it is working.. PERFECT .. Made few changes in the function because my table was based on Nested Set Model .. All the categories are migrated with their original hierarchy. Thank you very very much dude !!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to migrate your data to a different (and even custom-built) CMS, you should use [Export](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen), which will generate a WXR (XML) file that is very easy to parse and import into third-party systems. It includes all post types, taxonomies, meta data, attachments and everything else.

Working directly with the database is a pain, but if you will, it'll be easier to work on the WordPress side write the data into your other tables, rather than trying to read the data from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you  .. but my purpose is a bit different and my tables are based on nested model.. so that export actually wont work for me.. Anyway @vstm 's solution works like charm!! :)

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense. It doesn't really matter what your new structure is, all I'm saying is that it's easier to work with a well-structured XML export file, than it is to dig into the WordPress database tables and trying to make sense out of them. It could have saved you a lot of time, but looks like you went the hard way. Oh well ;)